# Change subscript font size in ConTeXt

Tags: formatting, fontsize, context

In ConTeXt, is it possible to make subscript font larger (but not other parts) in math formulas? I'd be happier if it takes effect document-globally.

I'm creating a document like this (my real example is more complicated due to a typescript definition involving Japanese...):

```
\starttypescript [myscript]
\definetypeface [myscript] [rm] [serif] [termes]
\definetypeface [myscript] [mm] [math]  [termes] [default] [rscale=1.085]
\stoptypescript

\usetypescript[myscript]
\setupbodyfont[myscript,11pt]


\starttext

Let $(a_x,a_y)$ be the position of ...
%%      ^---^--- bit too small

Let $K_{1,p}$ be the graph with ...
%%      ^^^----- bit too small

\stoptext
```

And I feel subscripts (x, y, "1,p") are bit too small.

In LaTeX it can be done by `\DeclareMathSizes{10}{9.5}{7}{5}` for example.

I don't know if this is relevant, but the [ConTeXt wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definetypeface) says the 5th argument to `\definetypeface` "specifies specific font size setups", though I couldn't find further information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are looking for `\definebodyfont` but I can't make an example right now.